# A new text should be displayed in textview every time the app launches

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a textview in MainActivity.java. There are 5 strings (sentences) which are stored in firebase database. What I want is every time the MainActivity.java launches, a new string should be fetched from the database and must be displayed in the textview. But it only fetches the first string. I am not sure how to make this work! Is there any workaround? Any Help is appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class Gridshow extends AppCompatActivity{
TextView myText;
private DatabaseReference database;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
        myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Attri);
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("StringList");
        database.child("String1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String sentName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            myText.setText(sentName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Sample son file:**

```
{
     "StringList" : {
      "String1" : "Valley Rovers",
      "String2" : "John Murphy",
      "String3" : "Hello all",
      "String4" : "See you all",
      "String5" : "Hey all"
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're directly saying to FB to retrieve just the first string in here:

```
 database.child("String1").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String sentName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            myText.setText(sentName);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

You should retrieve the whole list and randomly choose the new string:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
 database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           Map<String, String> entries = (Map<String, String>)   dataSnapshot.getValue();
            stringList.addAll(entries.values());
            selectString(stringList);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


public void selectString(ArrayList<String> list){
   Random ran = new Random();
   int x = ran.nextInt(list.size());
   myText.setText(list.get(x));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you add up as to how to select random entry and apply to textview as I am not sure how to do that!

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) Will apply this technique and let you know soon!

Comment: I get the following error on line `String sentName = snapshot.getValue(String.class);` `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String`

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("StringList");
    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() 
  {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String sentName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        myText.setText(sentName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this line:

```
database.child("String1").addValueEventListener
```

You are fetching just String1. You should instead use something like this:

```
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(int i = 0;i<dataSnapshot.getChildren().size();i++){
               if(i==positionOfStringYouWant){                 
                  String sentName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                   myText.setText(sentName);
               }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: how to set the value of `positionOfStringYouWant` ?